# Magento 1.9 Custom Module Front rout was going to 404, Now Showing Blank page instead of showing real information

Tags: magento-1.9, module, frontend, tabs, router

Created a custom module with admin grid and a front end rout admin section is working fine but when i visit the front end page it was going to 404 that issue is fixed now Showing Blank page instead of showing real information.

Here is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MageSf_OrderCustom>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </MageSf_OrderCustom>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Block</class>
        </ordercustom>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Helper</class>
        </ordercustom>
    </helpers>

    <models>         
        <magesf_ordercustom>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>magesf_ordercustom_resource</resourceModel>
        </magesf_ordercustom>
        <magesf_ordercustom_resource>
            <class>MageSf_OrderCustom_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <review>
                    <table>magesf_ordercustom</table>
                </review>
            </entities>
        </magesf_ordercustom_resource>
    </models>

    <resource>
        <magesf_ordercustom_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>MageSf_OrderCustom</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </magesf_ordercustom_setup>
        <magesf_ordercustom_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </magesf_ordercustom_write>
        <magesf_ordercustom_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </magesf_ordercustom_read>
    </resource>
</global>       
<adminhtml>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <ordercustom>
                <file>magsf_ordercustom.xml</file>
            </ordercustom>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
 <frontend>    
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <ordercustom>
                <file>ordercustom.xml</file>
            </ordercustom>
        </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
   <admin> 
   <routers>
     <adminhtml> 
         <args> 
             <modules> 
                <MageSf_OrderCustom after="Mage_Adminhtml">MageSf_OrderCustom_Adminhtml</MageSf_OrderCustom> 
            </modules> 
        </args>
   </adminhtml>  
  </routers> 
 </admin>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
        <ordercustom>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MageSf_OrderCustom</module>
                <frontName>Order Attachment</frontName>
            </args>
        </ordercustom>
     </routers>  
    </frontend>
```

here is the front end layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
     <customer_account>        
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">           
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="ordercustom">
        <name>ordercustom</name>
    <path>ordercustom/customer/view</path>
    <label>Order Attachments</label>
    </action>
</reference>
</customer_account>    

<ordercustom_customer_view>
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="ordercustom/ordercustom" name="view.ordercustom" template="ordercustom/customer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
</ordercustom_customer_view>
</layout>
```

And this is the controller file for front end module:

```
<?php

 class MageSf_OrderCustom_CustomerController extends    Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {    
/**
 * Checking if user is logged in or not
 * If not logged in then redirect to customer login
 */
   public function preDispatch()
     {
       parent::preDispatch();

       if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this))  {
        $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);

    // adding message in customer login page
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
            ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('ordercustom')->__('Please sign in or create a new account'));
    }
}            

/**
 * View Your Module
 */
public function viewAction()
{                    
$this->loadLayout();        
       $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Order Attachment'));        
$this->renderLayout();
  }
 } 
?>
```

Comment: what is the url u are trying in front nd?

Comment: that one is fixed now it is showing blank page instead showing the real data on my page. can you please check that.  @Mujahidh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your XML file at below place

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <ordercustom>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MageSf_OrderCustom</module>
                <frontName>ordercustom</frontName>
            </args>
        </ordercustom>
     </routers>  
    </frontend>
```

In frontname you have entered "Order Attachment" where **`space is not allowed`**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see this and fixed. appreciate your effort.

Comment: Welcome if its fixed for you please accept answer so it can help others as well.

Comment: There is an other issue i have land on the page but it is blank now.

Comment: Check error in layout.xml there will be problem in layout.xml file.

Comment: that is up with this question can you please have a look?

Comment: I didn't get you ? Means ?

Comment: means layout.xml is added to this question and also i have put my controller code please can you check why it is showing blank page. @Magento2 Learner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55808/discussion-between-xabby-and-magento2-learner).

Answer (score 1):

Fix this there was an issue with front route the front name was given wrong.

here how I create the front rout now and worked fine:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <ordercustom>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MageSf_OrderCustom</module>
                <frontName>ordercustom</frontName>
            </args>
        </ordercustom>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
```